# "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred" on Azure WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

**Could not find any solution on the web after hours and hours of research... Please help..**

I have a question that relates to internal server error or watever thats been happening..

**What i did that caused such error ?**

- The answer is nothing.. I only created a new web app -> WordPress and linked with free plan with clearDB mercury plan...

So, the first time that i did was a success however, when i linked it with my github repo. I had included .gitignore and only pushed wp-content files to github.. Seems when i synced azure merged only the files on the repo..

So, i deleted the resource again and started from scratch..

and now i have been getting this annoying error **"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."**

Checked kudu cmd, application settings.. could not find anything related... I mean i am not someone who has experience on azure.. So, anyone here please help out.. really frustated..

P.S i checked source code by logging through FTP as well .. everything seems to be in place...

**NOTE: This topic relates to a WordPress site.**

THANX

Comment: Just a thought, are you hosting your website on a shared server?  May be wise to speak with your hosting provider?  I regularly had this issue on shared servers.  Since migrating to a VPS server, I have not experienced this issue.

Comment: Yes testing on shared free hosting..

Comment: When thinking of a shared hosting server, think of a computer with many websites on.  The more websites a computer is hosting, the more it has to share its resources with.  Consequently, this will affect the overall performance for each website.  Once you have finished developing your website, you may wish to obtain your own server, so that your website does not have to share resources and thus, benefit from a better performance.